# how to insert lists in lists using r

Tags: r, mongodb

I have df looks like this

```
         df = data.frame(
          name = c('leo','brad','musk','mark'),
          vehicle = c(2,3,3,3),
          car = c(1,1,0,0),
          bike = c(1,0,1,1),
          bicycle = c(0,1,1,1),
          lorry = c(0,1,1,0))
```

df

```
name        vehicle     car     bike    bicycle     lorry
 leo          2         1       1       0           0
 musk         3         1       0       1           1
 mark         3         0       1       1           1
 uma          3         0       1       1           0
```

when I insert the above df to MongoDB using R, the JSON code looks like this

```
            {
            "name" : 'leo',
            "vehicle" : 2,
            "car" : 1,
            "bike" : 1,
            "bicycle" : 1,
            "lorry" : 0
        }
```

but I want it to be like this (like list within the list)

```
      {
        "name" : 'leo',
        "vehicle" : 2,
        "Total Vehicles": [
          {"car" : 1},
          {"bike" : 1},
          {"bicycle" : 0},
          {"lorry" : 0}
          ]

    }
```

in r, I have tried

```
cee = df[,c(1,2)]
com = list(df[,-c(1,2)])
see = append(cee, com)

sea =  list(var = df[,c(1,2)], comment = df[,-c(1,2)])
```

If the answer is already available. Please, provide me the link. thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        df1 = df[,c('name','vehicle')]



        df1$Total_Vehicles = df[,c('car','bike','bicycle','lorry')]



        > df1
          name vehicle Total_Vehicles.car Total_Vehicles.bike
        1  leo       2                  1                   1
        2 brad       3                  1                   0
        3 musk       3                  0                   1
        4 uma       3                  0                   1
          Total_Vehicles.bicycle Total_Vehicles.lorry
        1                      0                    0
        2                      1                    1
        3                      1                    1
        4                      1                    0



        > str(df1)
        'data.frame':   4 obs. of  3 variables:
         $ name          : Factor w/ 4 levels "brad","leo","uma",..: 2 1 4 3
         $ vehicle       : num  2 3 3 3
         $ Total_Vehicles:'data.frame': 4 obs. of  4 variables:
          ..$ car    : num  1 1 0 0
          ..$ bike   : num  1 0 1 1
          ..$ bicycle: num  0 1 1 1
          ..$ lorry  : num  0 1 1 0
```

And data when inserted into mongoDB JSON looks like this as required:

```
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a4107ccff03e12bf800141c"),
        "name" : "leo",
        "vehicle" : 2.0,
        "Total_Vehicles" : {
            "car" : 1.0,
            "bike" : 1.0,
            "bicycle" : 0.0,
            "lorry" : 0.0
        }
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a4107ccff03e12bf800141d"),
        "name" : "brad",
        "vehicle" : 3.0,
        "Total_Vehicles" : {
            "car" : 1.0,
            "bike" : 0.0,
            "bicycle" : 1.0,
            "lorry" : 1.0
        }
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a4107ccff03e12bf800141e"),
        "name" : "musk",
        "vehicle" : 3.0,
        "Total_Vehicles" : {
            "car" : 0.0,
            "bike" : 1.0,
            "bicycle" : 1.0,
            "lorry" : 1.0
        }
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a4107ccff03e12bf800141f"),
        "name" : "uma",
        "vehicle" : 3.0,
        "Total_Vehicles" : {
            "car" : 0.0,
            "bike" : 1.0,
            "bicycle" : 1.0,
            "lorry" : 0.0
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps `tidyr::nest()` will create the object as desired? it can be reversed using `unnest()`

**df1**

```
  name vehicle car bike bicycle lorry
1  leo       2   1    1       0     0
2 musk       3   1    0       1     1
3 mark       3   0    1       1     1
4  uma       3   0    1       1     0
```

**df2**

```
df2 <- df1 %>%
     nest(car:lorry, .key = 'total_vehicles')
```

Results in...

```
  name vehicle total_vehicles
1  leo       2     1, 1, 0, 0
2 musk       3     1, 0, 1, 1
3 mark       3     0, 1, 1, 1
4  uma       3     0, 1, 1, 0
```

where total_vehicles is a list column

```
str(df2)

'data.frame':   4 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ name          : Factor w/ 4 levels "leo","mark","musk",..: 1 3 2 4
 $ vehicle       : int  2 3 3 3
 $ total_vehicles:List of 4
  ..$ :'data.frame':    1 obs. of  4 variables:
  .. ..$ car    : int 1
  .. ..$ bike   : int 1
  .. ..$ bicycle: int 0
  .. ..$ lorry  : int 0
  ..$ :'data.frame':    1 obs. of  4 variables:
  .. ..$ car    : int 1
  .. ..$ bike   : int 0
  .. ..$ bicycle: int 1
  .. ..$ lorry  : int 1
  ..$ :'data.frame':    1 obs. of  4 variables:
  .. ..$ car    : int 0
  .. ..$ bike   : int 1
  .. ..$ bicycle: int 1
  .. ..$ lorry  : int 1
  ..$ :'data.frame':    1 obs. of  4 variables:
  .. ..$ car    : int 0
  .. ..$ bike   : int 1
  .. ..$ bicycle: int 1
  .. ..$ lorry  : int 0
```

Comment: I think you mean `tidyr::nest()`  (`purrr::nest` doesn't exist). And you can add `%>% jsonlite::toJSON(pretty = T)` to show it in the desired JSON